# Recursive Programming in R

Tags: r, recursion

I have a data frame in R (Df) that looks like this (with much more rows):

```
>Df
   eventName                time
1          A 2014-11-19 00:01:43
2          B 2014-11-19 00:05:31
3          B 2014-11-19 00:05:36
4          A 2014-11-19 00:05:36
5          E 2014-11-19 00:05:42
6          C 2014-11-19 00:05:49
7          E 2014-11-19 00:05:49
8          A 2014-11-19 00:05:55
9          E 2014-11-19 01:17:37
10         B 2014-11-19 01:17:40
11         C 2014-11-19 01:17:40
12         A 2014-11-19 01:17:47
```

I would like to generate a list with a sequence of events based on events happening within one hour relative to an initial event (considered as a reference). For example, in the dataframe above, the elements of the list would be:

```
[[1]]
[1] A B B A E C E A

[[2]]
[1] E B C A
```

In words, up to the 8th event, they all happen within an hour relative to the 1st event. Then, the new "reference" becomes event 9 and up to the 12th event they all happen within one hour (and so on in the original data frame).

I am not familiar with recursive programming, but it seems to me that this "problem" could be solved recursively(?). At the moment, the following function would work for the 1sr group of events.

```
seq <- c()
createSeq <- function(i) {
    j = i+1

    seq <-append(seq, as.character(Df$eventName[i]))

    while(difftime(Df$time[j],Df$time[i], units = "hours") <= 1){
        seq <- append(seq, as.character(Df$eventName[j]))
        j = j+1
    }        
    return(seq)
}            

createSeq(1)
[1] "A" "B" "B" "A" "E" "C" "E" "A"
```

(I am aware of the limited quality of the code). I guess recursively calling this function would do the job, but, after a number of attempts, I can't figure out how to code it and how to write it into a list.

Any ideas? of course, any other programming approach is also perfect for me.

Comment: The data.table package I believe, has a function that merges data frames based on the key within a window of each other. That function could be used to accomplish what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some question on what was intended here.  Was it:

1. break into two groups only with the first group being those rows with a time within one hour of the first row
2. break time into hours starting at the time of the first row and assign the rows according to which hour their time falls in
3. break into multiple groups with each group being those rows whose time is within an hour of the first row in that group

**1)** The first two problems are much easier and do not require recursion so I am assuming you meant the last; however,  if you meant the first then use

```
split(DF$eventName, DF$time >= DF$time[1] + 3600)
```

This splits it into A B B A E C E A and E B C A.

**2)** and if you want the second use

```
split(DF$eventName, cut(DF$time - as.numeric(DF$time[1]), "hour"))
```

which gives the same split in this case but might give different answers in other cases and in particular unlike the prior approach might produce more than 2 groups.

**3)** Here `recursiveSplit` splits the data frame into a list of data frames recursively.   It accepts a data frame or list of data frames and in the former case it puts it in a list.  Then it splits the last component of the list into two and if this was unsuccessful because there is only one component in the split then it returns; otherwise, it appends the first part of the split to the list and splits the second part recusrively.

Below run the recusrive function computing a list of data frames `S`.  From that we can compute a list of event name vectors or a group vector which identifies the group of each row.  If we used `sec = 3600` we would get the same split as above but just to illustrate more than 2 groups let us use `sec = 100` in the test run below:

```
recursiveSplit <- function(L, time = "time", sec = 3600) {
      if (is.data.frame(L)) L <- list(L)
      n <- length(L)
      last <- L[[n]]
      spl <- split(last, last[[time]] >= last[[time]][1] + sec)
      if (length(spl) == 1) L
      else Recall(unname(c(L[-n], spl)), time = time, sec = sec)
}

# test run - use 100 sec to get > 2 groups; S is a list of data frames
S <- recursiveSplit(list(DF), time = "time", sec = 100)
```

from `S` we can easily extract the event names:

```
> lapply(S, "[[", "eventName")
[[1]]
[1] A
Levels: A B C E

[[2]]
[1] B B A E C E A
Levels: A B C E

[[3]]
[1] E B C A
Levels: A B C E
```

or compute a grouping variable showing which group each row is in:

```
> rep(seq_along(S), sapply(S, nrow))
[1] 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3
```

**Note:** We used this as `DF`:

```
DF <- structure(list(eventName = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "E"), class = "factor"), 
    time = structure(c(1416373303, 1416373531, 1416373536, 1416373536, 
    1416373542, 1416373549, 1416373549, 1416373555, 1416377857, 
    1416377860, 1416377860, 1416377867), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), .Names = c("eventName", "time"), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Update:** Fixes and simplifications.

Comment: Hi G. Grothendieck, Effectively, was option 3 what I wanted, and your code is very elegant (and effective). thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You probably could do it recursively, but it's much easier just to use a loop.

step 1.  Create a variable that determines the group of each row.
step 2.  apply whatever function you need over each group.

```
x =  "
A\t2014-11-19 00:01:43
B\t2014-11-19 00:05:31
B\t2014-11-19 00:05:36
A\t2014-11-19 00:05:36
E\t2014-11-19 00:05:42
C\t2014-11-19 00:05:49
E\t2014-11-19 00:05:49
A\t2014-11-19 00:05:55
E\t2014-11-19 01:17:37
B\t2014-11-19 01:17:40
C\t2014-11-19 01:17:40
A\t2014-11-19 01:17:47
"
con = textConnection(x)
df = read.table(con, sep="\t")
close(con)
names(df) = c("eventName", "time")

#step 1
#find the grouping of each sample
timeGroup = numeric(nrow(df)) 
group = 1
startTime = df[1,2]
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){

    if(difftime(df$time[i],startTime, units = "hours") > 1){
        group = group + 1   
        startTime = df$time[i]
    }
    timeGroup[i] = group
    timeGroup
}
df$timeGroup = timeGroup

#step 2
#perform your function by group
by(df, timeGroup, function(x){
    #whatever you need to do here.
    x$eventName
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem right, here is one (non-recursive) solution, assuming your rows are in order of `time`:

```
with(Df, {
    time <- as.POSIXct(time)
    time.1st.diff <- c(0, as.numeric(diff(Df$time), units='hours'))
    cuml.hrs <- Reduce(function(x, y) {
        if (x + y > 1) 0 else x + y
    }, time.1st.diff, accumulate=TRUE)
    split(eventName, findInterval(seq_along(eventName), which(cuml.hrs == 0)))
})

# $`1`
# [1] "A" "B" "B" "A" "E" "C" "E" "A"
# 
# $`2`
# [1] "E" "B" "C" "A"
```

**EDIT** Prior answer did not generalize